# How can i reverse integer/non-integer value in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following integer value :

```
50326518
```

Now I want to convert it into in reverse but I want output like :

```
18653250
```

I used `reverse()` function but it returns 81562305, but I want output like `18653250`

How can I do this?

Sometime values can be like this `F4180000`

Comment: Is your `int` always 8 characters?

Comment: @MJH No. may be sometime it will be  like 'F4180000' .

Comment: Well, `'F4180000'` is not an integer

Comment: Yes. sorry it was my mistake to post question.

Comment: Ok, you got a string, is it always 8 characters?

Comment: yes. it always 8 characters.

Comment: Is that actually a hexadecimal integer representation and you want to reverse the byte order?

Comment: yes it is hexadecimal integer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I hope the following works on your 2008 version. I'm not certain about the support for `convert()` styles of the given hexstring. I'm on 2014. If it doesn't work, I will delete or edit the answer, please comment accordingly.

Since it's a hexstring and you want to actually reverse byte order, you can `convert()` it to a `varbinary` and use `reverse()` on that. That will reverse it byte for byte. `convert()` back to `varchar` in the end.

```
SELECT convert(varchar(max), convert(varbinary(max), reverse(convert(varbinary(max), '50326518', 2))), 2)
```

Prints:

```
18653250
```

Note, for some reason I had to explicitly `convert()` the return value of `reverse()` again as otherwise some implicit cast to `varchar` seems to happen. So this is intentional.

Maybe also consider storing the data as `binary` or possibly `int`. Otherwise it's hard to enforce sane data (I could insert all sorts of funny things in a string, that aren't hex at all.)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
select (right(col, 2) + substring(col, 5, 2) + substring(col, 3, 2) + left(col, 2)) as byte_reversed
```